# Como capturar o valor do body (Stream) de uma requisição sem apagá-lo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando capturar o body de uma requisição em uma classe de autorização (AuthorizationHandler), porém pelo fato desse body ser uma Stream, após ler seu conteúdo a requisição post que vem em seguida não pode ser executada pois a stream já foi lida e seu conteúdo não existe mais.

Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, Autorizacao requirement)
{
    var routeValues = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
    if (routeValues != null)
    {
        var obj = StreamToObject(routeValues.HttpContext.Request.Body);
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

private Object StreamToObject(Stream stream)
{
    try
    {
        string content;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Sei que isso está acontecendo pois após ler a stream seu conteúdo esta sendo descartado, mas eu gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para contornar esse problema ?

Comment: o que vem nesse stream?

Comment: @miltoncamara Um json em formato string que transformo em um objeto.

Comment: você envia no mesmo request um form e um json? Será que entendi direito?

Comment: Eu envio somente um json no body do POST.

Comment: Este projeto é uma webapi?

Comment: Sim, alterei o código acima para ficar mais claro. Isso faz parte da autenticação de uma api

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62738/discussion-between-miltoncamara-and-carlinhos).